# ggplot2 adding custom error bars and drawing horizontal line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot with custom values (including custom error bars). There are 5 variables with 3 values each. One of the values is the mean, and the other 2 values are 95% confidence values that are based on linear regression. I am having trouble representing a graph wih error bars.

I have the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
~variables, ~values,
'Concentration', -16.05,
'Concentration', -19.83,
'Concentration', -12.16,
'Progressive motile', -22.81,
'Progressive motile', -27.88,
'Progressive motile', -17.94,
'Total', -19.05,
'Total', -23.21,
'Total', -15.18,
'Motiliy %', -1.58,
'Motiliy %', -0.38,
'Motiliy %', 3.43,
'Volume', -1.97,
'Volume', -3.77,
'Volume', -0.55,
)

new_levels <- df$variables %>% unique %>% rev
df <- df %>% mutate(variables = factor(variables, levels = new_levels))
df %>% ggplot( aes(x=values, y=variables)) + coord_flip() + geom_point() + geom_line() + 
theme_classic() + xlab("Change (%)") + ylab("") + theme(
axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 2),
axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = +3))
```

[image: Here is how the graph looks like]

[image: And how it should look like]

So basically I just want to add horizontal lines.

Also how do I reverse the order of the variables?

CHeers

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest approach would be to add a column to your dataset which identifies which value corresponds to the mean and which are lower and upper bound of your confidence interval. Afterwards you could reshape your dataset to wide and add the errobars via a `geom_errobar`. And if you want to "reverse" the order of the variables then use the order as they appear in your dataset for which I use `unique()`:

Note: For the `'Motiliy %'` variable the order of the values seems different than for the other variables. So you probably have to fix that before reshaping.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df |>
  mutate(
    variables = factor(variables, levels = unique(variables)),
    stat = rep(c("y", "ymin", "ymax"), 5)
  ) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = stat, values_from = values) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = variables, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), width = .3) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(y = "Change (%)", x = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit:

Use `stat_summary` function:

```
df %>% 
     ggplot( aes(x=variables, y=values)) + 
     geom_point()  + 
     stat_summary(fun = median, fun.min = min, fun.max = max,
                  geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1)+ 
     theme_classic() + 
     labs(x = NULL, y = 'Change (%)')
```

[image]

---

You could invoke `row_number` or even `rank` etc then you can add the other ggplot geoms

```
df %>%
    mutate(name = row_number(values), .by = variables) %>%
    pivot_wider(values_from = values, names_prefix = 'y') %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = variables, y = y2)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = y1, ymax = y3), width = .1) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(y = "Change (%)", x = NULL) + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = 2),
          axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = 3))
```

[image]